# Create random-path by randomly choosing from lists of stored turtle-graphics functions

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics

I have stored turtle-graphics functions in list and am using random functions to call it to create a random-path, however code does not work.

Can someone please have a look on this and provide suggestion.

```
from turtle import Turtle
from turtle import Screen
import random

pen = Turtle()
pen.pensize(8)
pen.speed(10)
window = Screen()
window.colormode(255)

moves=[pen.forward(30),pen.backward(30)]
turns=[pen.right(90),pen.left(90)]

is_true = True

while is_true:
    pen.color(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))
    random.choice(turns)
    random.choice(moves)

window.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execute the methods only when you define the two list. Change the relevant part of the code like this

```
moves=[pen.forward, pen.backward]
turns=[pen.right, pen.left]

while True:
    pen.color(random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255))
    random.choice(turns)(90)
    random.choice(moves)(30)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say the issue here is that you are using *functions* as data when you could simply use *data* as data.  That is, giving `forward()` a negative distance is the same as `backward()`.  Giving `left()` a negative angle is the same as `right()`.  So we can simply do:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import random, choice

DISTANCES = [30, -30]
ANGLES = [90, -90]

def move():
    turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
    turtle.left(choice(ANGLES))
    turtle.forward(choice(DISTANCES))

    screen.ontimer(move, 10)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.pensize(8)
turtle.speed('fastest')

move()

screen.exitonclick()
```

I also dealt the next issue, your implicit `while True:`.  The way you structured your code, the `exitonclick()` is never reached and doesn't work.  Now it works as we've kept both the drawing and `exitonclick()` in the event loop.

Comment: Definitely the better choice :) also that you addressed the `while True` issue. *This* should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you don't list function calls in the lists `moves` and `turns` but the results of the calls. The second problem is that you don't call functions after the `random.choice` calls. What you are actually getting from this is the flickering effect of the visible pen tip that endlessly changes the color.

On way to fix it is already shown in buran's answer. Another way that keeps the turn and move arguments out of the loop is the following, here `lambda :` transforms the function calls into anonymous functions to which references are stored in `moves` and `turns`:

Another option is to extract the actual moves and turns into functions

```
from turtle import Turtle
from turtle import Screen
import random

pen = Turtle()
pen.pensize(8)
pen.speed(10)
window = Screen()
window.colormode(255)
 
moves=[lambda : pen.forward(30), lambda : pen.backward(30)]
turns=[lambda : pen.right(90), lambda : pen.left(90)]

for _ in range(100):
    pen.color(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))
    random.choice(turns)()
    random.choice(moves)()

window.exitonclick()
```

I decided to only draw 10 lines, so the turtle will most likely remain on screen. For a better way to get rid of the `while True` loop (including explanation) see cdlane's answer!

Comment: Thank you so very much for the explanation. helped a lot to debug the issue and its working now.